# How to access to controllers and retrieve data from the database while using vue-router?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vue-router

**What i want:** Trying to build a simple SPA using vuejs and vue-router. Simply retrieve data from the database and display it to the user. I have adjusted the laravel routes to match the vue-router. But I don't know **how to get data from database using vue-router**.

**What I did and some description:**

1. my vue-router

```
const routes = [
    {path:'/path', component: 'component},
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes 
});
```

2. file routes

```
Route::get('/{all}', 'Controller@methods')->where(['all' => '.*']);
```

**Additional description**: 
I was able to display the template of the components with the above code. However, I don't know how to retrieve data or **how to manipulate multiple controllers like 'laravel's routes'**.

Comment: You should use the `api.php` to declare endpoints, and make api calls prefixed with `/api/[whatever_route_you_declare]`
By default each route declared in `api.php` is prefixed

Comment: @ka_lin Thanks for your answer, I did it. But I have one more problem, hope you can help me. Every time I reload the web, the data is lost. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks